# Filter data using a search query? Wordpress JSON object + VueJS2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, wordpress-rest-api

**EDIT: Live Code Editor added: https://ide.c9.io/dosstx/wordpress**

I am trying to filter a Wordpress JSON data object using VueJS2 and the Wordpress REST API (I have a custom post type in my real world example).

I'm having trouble with the wiring and getting the table to filter based on the search terms that are typed into the search box.

**Without the search function, everything works fine, but once I try to filter using a searchterm, nothing happens -- no error in console.**

> I have my Vue instance like so:

```
var vm =  new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            searchTerm: '',
            posts: []
        },
        computed: {
            filteredItems: function(){
                return this.posts.filter(function(post) {
                    return this.post.searchTerm; //i believe this line is the culprit
                });
             }
        },
        created: function(){
            $.get('mylocalhost/wp-json/wp/v2/products/' + '?_embed=true')
                .done(function(data) {
                    vm.posts = data;
                 });
         }
 });
```

> My HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <form>
        <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm">
    </form>
```

> And further down my HTML....:

```
<tr v-for="post in filteredItems">
    <td>{{post.title.rendered}}</td>
   ...snip ...
</div>
```

Any clues on how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the `filter` method correctly.

From the [MDN Docs for the `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> `filter()` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns a value that coerces to `true`.

The callback passed to `filter` should return a `Boolean` value to determine whether or not to include the element of the array in the filtered array.

In your case, I'm assuming your `post` objects have some property (say `content`) you want to search and that you want to only include posts with content that contain the search term. So you can do something like this:

```
computed: {
  filteredItems: function() {
    return this.posts.filter(function(post) {
      return post.content.indexOf(this.searchTerm) != -1; 
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm stil not having any luck but I'm going to try and get  a working demo out for review. I'll post an updated link soon.

Comment: I've created a live editor for you. Can you take a look at my demo? I can't seem to filter the list: https://ide.c9.io/dosstx/wordpress

Comment: The issue was that you were trying to call `indexOf` on the post object, but you need to call it on whatever string property you want to search on. In general, jsfiddle.net is a much better way to share this type of code. [Here's a link to a fiddle I made with your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/3vyxLqgf/) I updated it to search on each post's `title` property's `rendered` string.

Comment: thank you that worked! Is it posisble to search the whole object and not just the title?